# How to open Visual Studio Code from the command line on linux?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know I can use command "code" to open VS code or file, but I don't know what should I do to make it possible after I install VS code in Ubuntu.Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to navigate to the project folder using Terminal and then typing `code .` ?

Answer (score 18):

Launching from the Command Line
You can launch VS Code from the command line to quickly open a file, folder, or project. Typically, you open VS Code within the context of a folder. We find the best way to do this is to simply type:

```
code .
```

Tip: We have instructions for Mac users in our Setup topic that enable you to start VS Code from within a terminal. We add the VS Code executable to the PATH environment variable on Windows and Linux automatically during installation.
Sometimes you will want to open or create a file. If the specified files does not exist, VS Code will create them for you:

```
code index.html style.css readme.md
```

Tip: You can have as many file names as you want separated by spaces.

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics

Comment: Worked for me, open terminal cd /project/root/dir and type code . and got complete file open in VS Code.

Comment: Nice! And, the program does not stay running in the terminal, so you can do other things in the terminal or close it without closing VS Code.

Answer (score -1):

So, there are a couple of solutions for this.
I've linked a video that shows you how to add vscode to $PATH
(which didn't work for me because I couldn't find the "shell:install path" command)

I uninstalled the vscode from my ubuntu and re-installed using sudo snap install --classic code
(This method worked for me)

Tell me which one works for you... and if you have extensions installed to your vscode then i guess you ought to make a backup or something.

Link to the video: https://youtu.be/iP5FKZXtDBs

Comment: While the video might be useful, it's better to have a summary of the solution here (this applies to links in answers on SO as well), in the case of link rot, and in the case of videos, accessibility.